# Why is the trimmed down shared_ptr version here slower than boost::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, performance, boost, shared-ptr, reference-counting

I thought this is already very simple and not doing much (Took it from one of the stack overflow question answer code), but running a loop of 100K times shows it's slower than boost::shared_ptr.  Baffled, where is the slowness come from?

```
template <class T>
class sp_shared_ptr
{
public:
        inline sp_shared_ptr() noexcept: p_(), count_() {}

        inline explicit sp_shared_ptr( T* p ) noexcept: p_( p ), count_( new int(1) )   {}

        inline sp_shared_ptr( const sp_shared_ptr& sp ) noexcept: p_( sp.p_ ), count_( sp.count_ )
        {
                if( count_ ) ++(*count_);
        }

        // EDIT: add in later based on comments
        sp_shared_ptr( sp_shared_ptr && r ) noexcept : p_( r.p_ ), count_()
        {
                int *tmp = r.count_;
                r.count_ = count_;
                count_ = tmp;
                r.p_ = 0;
        }

        sp_shared_ptr& operator=( const sp_shared_ptr& sp ) noexcept
        {
                if( this != &sp )
                {
                        clear();
                        p_ = sp.p_;
                        count_ = sp.count_;
                        if( count_ ) ++*count_;
                }
                return *this;
        }

        ~sp_shared_ptr() noexcept
        {
                clear();
        }

private:
        inline void clear() noexcept
        {
                if( count_ )
                {
                        --*count_;
                        if( *count_ == 0 ) {
                             delete p_;  p_=0;
                             delete count_;  count_=0;
                        }
                }
        }

        T* get() const { return count_ ? p_ : 0; }
        T* operator->() const { return get(); }
        T& operator*() const { return *get(); }

        T* p_;
        int* count_;
};
```

The output of the following program is:

```
10229594
14577150
14030158
```

EDIT: Based on @BoPersson's comment, edit in the move constructor.  Now, result is getting closer:
    10201099
    14121221
    14040181

I wonder why it is faster, or quite a bit faster (No atomic counter didn't do any good in my test?)

Calling program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
#include <time.h>

#include "sp_shared_ptr.h"

struct A
{
  int a1;
  double a2;
  std::string a3;
};

long long duration( const timespec& t0, const timespec& t1 )
{
  return (t1.tv_sec*1000000000L + t1.tv_nsec) - (t0.tv_sec*1000000000L + t0.tv_nsec);
}

int main()
{
  typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> UPVector;
  typedef std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<A>> SPVector;
  typedef std::vector<sp_shared_ptr<A>> MySPVector;

  UPVector v1;
  SPVector v2;
  MySPVector v3;

  const int n=100000;
  timespec t0, t1;
  clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &t0 );

  clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &t0 );
  {
    for( auto i=0; i < n; ++i )
      v1.push_back( std::unique_ptr<A>( new A { i, i/100.0, "aaaaaaaaaa" } ) );
  }
  clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &t1 );
  std::cout << duration( t0, t1 ) << std::endl;

  clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &t0 );
  {
    for( auto i=0; i < n; ++i )
      v3.push_back( sp_shared_ptr<A>( new A{ i, i/100.0, "aaaaaaaaaa" } ) );
  }
  clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &t1 );
  std::cout << duration( t0, t1 ) << std::endl;

  clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &t0 );
  {
    for( auto i=0; i < n; ++i )
      v2.push_back( boost::shared_ptr<A>( new A{ i, i/100.0, "aaaaaaaaaa" } ) );
  }
  clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &t1 );
  std::cout << duration( t0, t1 ) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first thing you could do is take the source code of `boost::shared_ptr` and edit it step by step to eventually become identical to your own code. Measure after every step. You will find out what causes the difference.

Comment: One guess is that the Boost version might have a move constructor and move assignment.

Comment: `int* count_;` is not `atomic`, does that mean this `sp_shared_ptr` class is not thread safe ?

Comment: You say Boost is the faster one but your test results indicate std:: is the fastest.  Confusing.

Comment: @JohnZwinck it is `std::unique_ptr` which is the fastest which is not  confusing.

Comment: Are the results the same if you reverse the order of the tests? (in each test more memory is allocated). I think I would also remove string a3 from the class for this test.

Comment: @Danny_ds I tried putting sp_shared_ptr at end, still, boost::shared_ptr is faster.

Comment: @surfcode I would have put it as the first test, where more (bigger blocks of) memory is/are still available (and currently has the best time). It probably won't make a difference, but then you would be sure.

Comment: @Danny_ds, jus tried.  didn't make any differences

Comment: @BoPersson thanks.  added the move constructor as well (looks like move assignment won't be called in this case).  It did get the results closer to boost::shared_ptr.  Running a couple of times:
10201099
14121221
14040181
Still slower.  Wonder what I'm missing.  9 out of 10 times on a 100k times loop boost is still faster..

Comment: @JohnZwinck started the test code with playing around with different smart ptrs.  I guess I could have remove std::unique_ptr from the posted code to make it clearer.  Main question is why sp_shared_ptr is slower than boost::shared_ptr stuffing into vector and destroying..

Comment: You need to look at the generated code.